# Вывести индексы топ 3 игроков по уровню используя LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Я хочу из этого листа получить индексы топ 3 игроков с наибольшим уровнем, используя Linq.
Если можно, то наиболее простой способ, я только начал изучать LINQ.
Спасибо:)

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Player> players = new List<Player>()
            {
                new Player("Ян", 19),
                new Player("Владимир", 25),
                new Player("Дмитрий", 14),
                new Player("Леонид", 42),
                new Player("Виктория", 72), //index 4
                new Player("Елена", 55),
                new Player("Евгений", 55),
                new Player("Михаил", 45),
                new Player("Роман", 75), // index 8
                new Player("Николай", 85),  //index 9
                new Player("Александр", 15),
                new Player("Петр", 25),
            };
        }    
    }

    class Player
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public int Level { get; private set; }

        public Player(string name, int level)
        {
            Name = name;
            Level = level;
        }
    }
```

Ответ будет таков: индексы 9 8 4

Comment: `players.OrderByDescending(p => p.Level).Take(3)`?

Comment: и что это будет? сортируем по убыванию и берём первые три. И какие у меня индексы будут? 0 1 2? 
В моём ответе должны быть индексы 9 8 4

Comment: А причём тут индексы? Вы попробуйте код-то.

Comment: @VladD я попробовал, у меня получается лист из первых трёх элементов, взятых из листа, отсортированного по убыванию. Как мне из этого получить индексы?

Comment: А зачем вам индексы вообще? У вас же есть сами элементы. Индексы-то получить можно, но какой в этом смысл?

Comment: у меня такое условие задачи. Задача в другом немного, эту задачу я привел чтобы было более понятно, она идентична той. В той задаче есть коробка с банками, и часть банок бракованная. Мне нужно получить индексы этих бракованных банок

Comment: Ну вот например: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mYs45b. Но условие плохое: вам никогда не должны быть нужны индексы, только сами элементы.

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но это слишком сложно, другого способа полегче нет?)

Comment: Да куда уж проще? Ну уберите `ThenBy`, если хотите проще

Answer (score 4):

Самый простой метод, видимо, такой:

```cs
var bestIndices =
    players.Select((p, idx) => (p.Level, idx))    // преобразуем данные: нам нужны пары
                                                  // из уровня и индекса
           .OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Level) // сортируем по убыванию уровня
           .Select(pair => pair.idx)              // убираем уровень из данных,
                                                  // оставляем только индексы
           .Take(3);                              // берём 3 верхних
```

Но скорее всего вам не должны быть нужны индексы, а только сами элементы. В этом случае ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```cs
var best = players.OrderByDescending(p => p.Level).Take(3);
```